# How to loop the array in the same time in VBA

Tags: vba, vba6

My problem is after the the `j` in the loop is done, the `i` will just move.

I want to the run the 2 loop array at the same time.

```
ReDim ArrayItems(Download_frm.ListBox1.ListCount)
ReDim ArrayItems1(Download_frm.accountb.ListCount)

For i = 1 To Download_frm.ListBox1.ListCount
   Download_frm.ListBox1.ListIndex = i - 1
   ArrayItems(i) = Download_frm.ListBox1.Text
 
   MsgBox ArrayItems(i)
   'myarray = ArrayItems(i)
 
 
   For j = 1 To Download_frm.accountb.ListCount
      Download_frm.accountb.ListIndex = j - 1
      ArrayItems1(j) = Download_frm.accountb.Text
 
      MsgBox ArrayItems1(j)
      'MsgBox ArrayItems1(j)

      accountli = ArrayItems1(j)
 
      'MsgBox ArrayItems(i)
 
      COCODELI = ArrayItems(i)
   Next j
Next i
```

Comment: VBA does not support multi threading, so you can't run them simultanously. Currently you run them nested.

Comment: You don't want to *"run the 2 loop array at the same time"*, that's not your goal. That's only how you currently think you can reach your goal. Describe your goal.